# How to tell if the server is locked?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

When the server is doing a long running operation like frontend indexing, how to tell programmatically if it's locked? My current code is like this:

```
def server_locked(timeout=5):
    con = pymongo.Connection(network_timeout=5)
    try:
        con.database_names()
        return False
    except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect:
        return True
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: set some evnironmental variable and use it like a semaphore... ?

Answer (score 1):

On the database, use `current_op()` to view operations in progress.
And `command('serverStatus')` to get a report on each lock.

Here's an example while doing a lot inserts:

```
connection = Connection()
db = connection.test_database
db.current_op()

{
  u'inprog': [
    {
      u'numYields': 0,
      u'lockStats': {
        u'timeAcquiringMicros': {
          u'r': 0L,
          u'w': 3L
        },
        u'timeLockedMicros': {

        }
      },
      u'waitingForLock': False,
      u'desc': u'conn1',
      u'connectionId': 1,
      u'locks': {
        u'^test': u'W',
        u'^': u'w'
      },
      u'client': u'127.0.0.1:64743',
      u'threadId': u'0x104681000',
      u'active': True,
      u'query': {

      },
      u'opid': 11199,
      u'ns': u'test.test',
      u'secs_running': 0,
      u'op': u'insert'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, how do I get what I want from this? Iterate `inprog` and check the `locks` field?

Comment: I believe so. I haven't tested this part. Remember that in 2.2 there is a database lock, while in previous versions there was a global server lock. See this [blog post](http://blog.serverdensity.com/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo Connection object has a property named `is_locked`.

[Documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.is_locked)

Comment: `is_locked` only returns the `fsyncLock` state, I'm interested in read locks as well.